# System.Drawing.Printing: The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: c#, winapi, printing, controls, rpc

I'm running some really basic print code: (using .net 4.0, VS 2012, Windows 8)

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);

control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height));

var pd = new PrintDocument();

pd.PrintPage += (s, e) => e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 100, 100);
pd.Print();
```

And it is throwing an error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
HResult=-2147467259
Message=The RPC server is unavailable
  Source=System.Drawing
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeErrorCode=1722
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
   at FrogJump.Form1.PrintControl(Control control) in e:\Univ\S13\AI\FrogJump\FrogJump\Form1.cs:line 120
   at FrogJump.Form1.btnPrint_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Univ\S13\AI\FrogJump\FrogJump\Form1.cs:line 108
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at FrogJump.Program.Main() in e:\Univ\S13\AI\FrogJump\FrogJump\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Comment: Neither System.Drawing.Printing nor the Windows printing api uses RPC.  You'll need to check out your printer driver first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really a long shot - but I think you should check if you are printing to the printer you think you are printing to.. ;)

(check if you are printing to the correct printer and it is turned on)

Comment: actually your comment helped!! Suddenly the error went away! The "default printer" was not attached to my pc at the time.... Still don't get why the error happened, but for now, at least the issue went away. :) thanks!!

Comment: To be honest it wasn't 'really' a long shot.. :) you were trying to print, only RPC in that scenario is your printer driver trying to send commands to your server (printer) which is probably unavailble.. "Message=The RPC server is unavailable"

Comment: For me, re-starting the Print Spooler service solved the problem

Comment: +1 - This answer is a good starting point for issues like this. In my case I was trying to print from a .NET application running on a VM not attached to the domain, so I guess I was not authenticated to the server I was trying to print to. Accessing said server with windows explorer prompted me for my credentials and once cached the printing worked from the .NET application.  What a thoroughly unhelpful error message though!